# Поиск подстроки в TreeSet

Tags: java, search, дерево

Есть список имён который храниться в `TreeSet`, нужно найти все имена начинающиеся с указанной подстроки, имена могут содержать любые символы. Я сделал следующем образом.

```
public static Set<String> searchNames(NavigableSet<String> data, String subString){
    return data.subSet(subString, subString + Character.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

Но как выяснилось это решение не совсем оптимально. У кого нибудь есть идеи как можно оптимизировать это решение? Может создать внутренний `TreeSet` и передать собственный компаратор? Но я пока не могу сообразить какое в нём должно быть условие и правильный ли это путь. Буду рад любой подсказке или намёку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня получилось такое решение. Вместо `TreeSet` использовать `List`. Отсортировать этот список, затем запускать на нем бинарный поиск с заданной подстрокой. Если эта подстрока является элементом списка, то начиная с этого индекса достаем элементы и проверяем у них префиксы. При первом несовпадении заканчиваем обход. Если подстрока не является элементом, то метод вернет следующее число `(- <позиция куда можно было бы вставить данный ключ> - 1)`. По полученному числу можно определить с какой позиции нужно начинать обход.

Код полностью:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("pear", "tree", "moscow", "t-shirt", "apple", "saratov");
    Collections.sort(list);

    System.out.println(search("tr", list));
}

public static List<String> search(String prefix, List<String> list) {
    int index = Collections.binarySearch(list, prefix);
    index = index >= 0 ? index : Math.abs(index) - 1;
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = index; i < list.size(); i++)
        if (list.get(i).startsWith(prefix))
            result.add(list.get(i));
        else
            break;

    return result;
}
```

Если сильно гонитесь за производительностью, рекомендую присмотреться к [префиксному дереву](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Set<String> searchNames(NavigableSet<String> data, String subString){
    String lastBound = null;
    for (String s : data.tailSet(subString)) {
        if (s.toLowerCase().startsWith(subString.toLowerCase())) {
            lastBound = s;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return data.subSet(subString, true, lastBound, true);
}
```

Время *O(log(n))*

Comment: На самом деле время не совсем O(logn). Потому что если длина строки 1000 символов, то вы не учитываете, что ее нужно проверятьв первом ифе. Следовательно нужно добавить еще m  пепед длиной. А второй момент, если tailSet вернетвесь текущий сет, почему будет логарифм?